# How to malloc a structure to a pointer that is already in another structure

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct

I've a structure that contains two pointers and a value. It is for a binary tree.

```
 struct node 
 {
  int value;        //holds value of node
  node *lesschild;  //pointer to lesser value child
  node *greatchild; //pointer to greater value child
 };
```

And this structure is pointed to by a pointer in a function called `addelement` and now I want to `malloc` another structure that is pointed to by one of the pointers in the original node or structure, I'm occurring syntax problems and I am looking for help.

This is what I've for creating another structure that is pointed to by `lesschild` which is in a structure that is pointed to by `ptr`.

I'm then trying to change value in the new structure through the double pointer.

```
ptr->lesschild = &malloc(sizeof(struct node));
ptr->lesschild->value = add;
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Thanks for you help

Comment: Why is `lesschild` an integer pointer instead of a node pointer?

Comment: Ask a question about the error message. What is it about the error message that confuses you?

Comment: lesschild is a node pointer that is a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close, it's:

```
ptr->lesschild = (node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
ptr->lesschild->value = add;  // assuming add is an int
```

`malloc` already returns a pointer. I'm assuming of course `lesschild` is actually a `node *` and you just made a typo.

Comment: Ok I tried that and now I am getting an error that says "invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'node*' " I should mention that these two lines are in a function that does not return any value.

Comment: You need to cast the result to `node *`, just like the error says. I added it to my answer.

Comment: @couchprogramer Stop using a C++ compiler! Alternatively, change your tag so it's a C++ question.

Comment: See the question entitled ["Do I cast the result of malloc"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) for more information...

Comment: This looks like homework so I doubt he can choose his compiler (or even knows what it means). Easier to just add the cast!

Comment: The odds are his compiler can be switched to compile either C89 or C99, without even using a different compiler. gcc (`g++ -std=c99`), clang (similar to gcc) and Microsoft C++ (can be switched to C89 only in project settings) are all most commonly used... In fact, I can't think of a single C++ compiler that doesn't have a corresponding C compiler running along-side.